# What is the right way to scale pdf content with Apache PdfBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have some pdf with data. Mission - put the image with some information at all pages (at one place: top, left, right, bottom of the page). But some pdfs has no place at this positions and i cant insert image over content. Thats why i need scaling. 
After days of trying and reading stackoverflow i make all that i need and "It's alive!!! Alive!!!" (c)... but not always...Since pdfbox 2.0.8, at some pdf (with Optional Content Properties) my function falls in recursive hell.

**This is the code:**

```
public static void putStamp(PDDocument document, X509Certificate certificate, UserInfo userInfo, TransformProperties transformProperties) throws IOException {
    final Map<StampSize, PDImageXObject> stampsUser = new HashMap<>();

    TransformProperties.Position posUserStamp = null;
    double scale = 1;

    if (transformProperties!=null){
        posUserStamp = transformProperties.getUserStampPosition();
        scale = ((double)transformProperties.getScale()) / 100;
    }

    final LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(document);

    Iterator<PDPage> iterator = document.getPages().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        PDPage page = iterator.next();
        PDPageContentStream stream;
        Boolean isRotatedPage = false;
        int rotateAngle = 0;

        final PDFormXObject obj = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(document, page);
        AffineTransform affineTransformScale1 = new AffineTransform(1,0, 0,1,0, 0);
        obj.setMatrix(affineTransformScale1);

        page.setResources(new PDResources());

        if(page.getRotation()==90 || page.getRotation()==270){
            isRotatedPage = true;
            rotateAngle = 360 - page.getRotation();
            page.setRotation(0);
            PDRectangle rectangle = new PDRectangle(page.getMediaBox().getHeight(),page.getMediaBox().getWidth());
            page.setMediaBox(rectangle);
            page.setCropBox(rectangle);
        }else if (page.getRotation()==180){
            isRotatedPage = true;
            rotateAngle = 360 - page.getRotation();
            page.setRotation(0);
        }

        float pageWidth = page.getBBox().getWidth();
        float pageHeight =  page.getBBox().getHeight();
        double newXcoordinates = (pageWidth - pageWidth*scale)  /2;
        double newYcoordinates = (pageHeight - pageHeight*scale)  /2;

        stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.OVERWRITE, true, true);
        stream.saveGraphicsState();
        if (isRotatedPage) {
            float offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
            switch (rotateAngle){
                case 270:
                    offsetX = 0;
                    offsetY = pageHeight;
                    break;
                case 180:
                    offsetX = pageWidth;
                    offsetY = pageHeight;
                    break;
                case 90:
                    offsetX = pageWidth;
                    offsetY = 0;
                    break;
            }
            stream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotateAngle), offsetX, offsetY));
        }

        AffineTransform affineTransformScale = new AffineTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, newXcoordinates, newYcoordinates);
        stream.transform(new Matrix(affineTransformScale));
        stream.drawForm(obj);
        stream.restoreGraphicsState();

        if (!Config.getInstance().isIgnoreUserStamp() && userInfo != null) {
            int posXuser = 0;
            int posYuser = 0;
            int stampH = 0;
            int stampW = 0;
            boolean rotate = false;
            if (posUserStamp == TransformProperties.Position.LEFT) {
                stampH = (int) (pageWidth / 32 * multiply);
                stampW = (int) (pageHeight * 0.9 * multiply);
                posXuser = (int) (pageWidth * 0.015);
                posYuser = (int) ((pageHeight - stampW/multiply) / 2 );
                rotate = true;
            }else if (posUserStamp == TransformProperties.Position.RIGHT){
                stampH = (int) (pageWidth / 32 * multiply);
                stampW = (int) (pageHeight * 0.9 * multiply);
                posXuser = (int) (pageWidth * 0.985 - (stampH / multiply)) ;
                posYuser = (int) ((pageHeight - (stampW / multiply)) / 2 );
                rotate = true;
            }else if(posUserStamp == TransformProperties.Position.BOTTOM){
                stampH = (int) (pageHeight / 32 * multiply);
                stampW = (int) (pageWidth * 0.9 * multiply);
                posXuser = (int) (pageWidth * 0.05);
                posYuser = (int) (pageHeight * 0.015);
            }else if(posUserStamp == TransformProperties.Position.TOP || posUserStamp == null) {
                stampH = (int) (pageHeight / 32 * multiply);
                stampW = (int) (pageWidth * 0.9 * multiply);
                posXuser = (int) (pageWidth * 0.05);
                posYuser = (int) (pageHeight * 0.985 - (stampH / multiply));
            }

            final StampSize stampSizeUser = new StampSize(stampW, stampH);

            PDImageXObject imageUser;
            if(stampsUser.containsKey(stampSizeUser)){
                imageUser = stampsUser.get(stampSizeUser);
            }else {
                BufferedImage img = createStampUser(stampSizeUser.width, stampSizeUser.height, userInfo);
                if (rotate) {
                    img = rotateImageByDegrees(img, 90);
                }
                imageUser = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, img);
            }
            stampsUser.put(stampSizeUser, imageUser);
            stream.drawImage(imageUser, posXuser, posYuser, imageUser.getWidth() / multiply, imageUser.getHeight() / multiply);
        }

        stream.close();

    }
}

public static BufferedImage rotateImageByDegrees(BufferedImage img, double degrees) {
    double rads = Math.toRadians(degrees);
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);
    int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

    BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);

    at.rotate(rads, w / 2, h / 2);
    g2d.setTransform(at);
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0,null);
    g2d.dispose();

    return rotated;
}
```

So, what i do:

1. I save current page as `PDFormXObject` and clear resources at page.

`final PDFormXObject obj = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(document, page);
AffineTransform affineTransformScale1 = new AffineTransform(1,0, 0,1,0, 0);
obj.setMatrix(affineTransformScale1);
page.setResources(new PDResources());`

2. Check if page rotated by `setRotation()` and set it to 0 with changing mediabox width and height. (because when it rotated by that way bottom on preview becomes left...or right...or top...this is not good for user)
3. Open stream with OVERWRITE, rotate if need, scale (by default scale=1) and `drawForm` from step 1.

   AffineTransform affineTransformScale = new AffineTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, newXcoordinates, newYcoordinates);
   stream.transform(new Matrix(affineTransformScale));
   stream.drawForm(obj);
   stream.restoreGraphicsState();
4. Create and draw stamp.

I feel what i do - it's wrong! Because at step 1 i use method `layerUtility.importPageAsForm(document, page);` created for import from other pdf...not the same pdf, if i got it right. And since pdfbox 2.0.8 at this method was add `importOcProperties(sourceDoc);` In this place i have infinite recursion in some pdfs. But how i can transform current page to PDFormXObject? Or how i can use Matrix to scale only content? (i try do it, but I failed...)

I don't know how make it correctly. I don't want to create new PDDocument and add pages to it, beacuse some pdfs more than 500 mb. In this case in memory will be 2 pdfs with size over 500 mb. I think this is wrong way...But how corretly take page, scale content (without change size od mediaBox and cropBox) and add stamp?

Second question about step 2: what a rigth way to make landscape or portrait? By setRotation or changing mediabox? IMHO: changing mediabox, but i'm newbie in pdf...

Please lead the rigth way!

P.S. i cant show pdfs...personal data...

Comment: Are you sure you need scaling? How about enlarging the pages? That would make things much easier...

Comment: @mkl First of all - big thanks to you! Your answers about pdfBox - is pretty brilliant! they are always useful! Many things i can understant only after reading your postst and examples. Big thanks!

Comment: @mkl about your idea of enlarging: Did I understand correctly that you mean increase size of mediaBox? somethig like PDRectangle(0,0,650,850) -> PDRectangle(-10,-10,660,860)? No, i don't think in that way...

Comment: *"Did I understand correctly that you mean increase size of mediaBox"* - media box and crop box (if a crop box is set), yes. But you enlarge it in all directions (PDRectangle(0,0,650,850) -> PDRectangle(-10,-10,660,860)) which is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @mkl Thanks to you!) i change my code as you say. Now i change boxs size. Only one feathire i lost - upscale. But it's not important.